# How do I get a specific value from an object through foreign key connection in django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, foreign-keys

guys!
I got the following table and want to get all scad files from objects of Model3D where part of is not null and has the same id as Model3D. Model3D is an 3D printer object that may consists of more than just one part and has therefore the "part of" attribute that holds the id of the original model.

```
class Model3D(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    original_Model = models.ForeignKey('Model3D', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    creation_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    stl_File = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='models/stlFiles')
    scad_File = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='models/scadFiles')
    parameter_id = models.ForeignKey('Parameter', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    part_of = models.ForeignKey('Model3D', related_name="part_of_model3d", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I tried the following: `part_models_scad_files = Model3D.objects.filter(part_of__isnull=False).select_related(id=self.id)`

but how do i get the scad files and not only the objects?

Thanks for your help, I really want to learn more!

Comment: So, you want to get an array of `scad_files`?

Answer (score 0):

You may not filter in a 'select_related', it is to call the related 'field name', seems to be no need for select_related, you can use Case 1 simply

In your case if you wanted to get results with specific ids you could use

Case 1

```
part_models_scad_files = Model3D.objects.get(part_of__isnull=False, id = self.id)
print(part_models_scad_files.scad_file)
```

Case 2 (for evaluating 2 tables)

```
part_models_scad_files = Model3D.objects.filter(part_of__isnull=False, id = self.id).select_related('part_of')
for entry in part_models_scad_files:
    print(entry.scad_file)
```

Case 3 (if you wanted only scad_file's list)

```
part_models_scad_files = Model3D.objects.filter(part_of__isnull=False, id = self.id).select_related('part_of').values_list('scad_file', flat = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use an [`F`-expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

```
part_models_scad_files = Model3D.objects.select_related('part_of').filter(part_of__isnull=False, id=F('id')).values_list('scad_File', flat=True)
```